# How to change urls for "Add", "Change" etc. buttons in Django Admin?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-admin

My Django admin panel on production server has url `https://example.com/app/admin`, but when I click on the buttons near my models (on the [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/feEdS.png)), I'm redirected to `https://example.com/admin/metrics/...`, without an `/app/` part.
If I manually go to `https://example.com/app/admin/metrics/...`, everything works perfectly.

Can I somehow override this behaviour without overriding the whole admin panel template?

Nginx config (relevant part):

```
...
    location = /app {
    return 302 https://$server_name/app/index.html;
}

location ~ ^/app/(.*)$ {
    include app_frontend;
    rewrite ^/app/(.*) /$1 break;
    proxy_pass http://unix:/opt/data/app/app.sock;
}
...
```

**UPD** solved this issue adding `FORCE_SCRIPT_NAME = '/app/'` in settings.py.

Comment: Is your Django app behind a webserver (e.g. nginx, apache) using a reverse proxy ? Or have you configured your urls.py to include this prefix for the admin?

Comment: @IainShelvington Yes, my Django app behind nginx

Comment: Can you share the nginx config for your app? And the config for uwsgi/gunicorn?

Comment: change route of admin url in your_project/urls.py

Comment: @MdShahbazAhmad it works if I add the following code: 

```urlpatterns = [
    path('app/admin/', admin.site.urls),  
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),  
...
```

But honestly it doesn't look like a perfect solution.

Comment: @IainShelvington updated my question with nginx config.